# Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've four screens in a Stack navigator in `Books.js`:

```
function Books(props) {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={BooksMenu} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Order Book" component={BookOrder} />
            <Stack.Screen name="My Books" component={MyBooks} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={MyBooksDetails} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
}
```

From the `BooksMenu` screen user is navigating to the `MyBooks` screen and from the `MyBooks` there is a button that navigates the user to `MyBooksDetails` screen.

This error pops-up with I click on the button that is supposed to navigate the user to `MyBooksDetails` from the `MyBooks` screen. This is how the button action is handled:

```
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback style={styles.detailsBtn}
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')} >
                <Text style={styles.detailsBtnText}>See Details</Text>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

I've restructured the default `props` with this on `BookCell` which is just a custom component in the `MyBooks` screen.

```
function BooksCell({ navigation }) {...
```

The screen which has the `BookCell` component still has default `props`.

```
function MyBooks(props) {...
```

So the sub screen (which is the component `BooksCell`) has `navigation` as a restructured prop and its parent screen `MyBooks` as default `props` and the parent screen of `MyBooks` which is `BooksMenu` also have `navigation` as a restructured prop.

```
function BooksMenu({ navigation }) {...
```

Hope this makes sense. I'm new to react native so I have an idea that might be wrong but not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Only the components which are the top-level screens will get the navigate prop.  If you want to access it in BooksCell then you need to pass it down from the parent or access it from the useNavigation hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destructuring of `({navigation})` vs. `(props)` does not make a difference.  The important thing is what props are provided when the component is called.

Writing `({navigation})` means that your component expects to be called with a `navigation` prop.  It doesn't provide that prop.

The top-level screens such as `MyBooks` and `BooksMenu` will be called with the props `navigation` and `route` when they are rendered by the Navigator.  `BooksCell` is not a screen so React Navigation will not provide it with any props.

If you want to use the prop `navigation` in `BooksCell` then you must provide it.  You can pass it down from a parent which has the prop.

```
function MyBooks(props) {
  ...
  return (
    <BooksCell navigation={props.navigation} />
  );
}
```

The other option is to access `navigation` in `BooksCell` through the [`useNavigation()` hook](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation), which gets the `navigation` object by using the current Navigator's context.

```
function BookCell() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  ...
}
```